# Operar valores nulos en Python con MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos de MongoDB y quiero que al hacer una consulta y el valor no este en la base de datos y solo se retorne la consola en blanco haga algo tipo

```
for documento in col.find({'# telefónico':8233323}):   #Query de consulta de mi base de datos
    a = print(documento)
    if a == None:
        print("No encontrado")
```

En este ejemplo ese número telefónico no existe en mi base de datos y quiero que al hacer la consulta y no exista el valor se devuelva "No encontrado", no se que estoy haciendo mal. Lo que presenté arriba es una modificación de las query de consulta ya que si lo pongo a como viene por defecto.

```
for documento in col.find({'# telefónico':8233323}):   #Query de consulta de mi base de datos
     print(documento)
```

Donde lo que devuelve es la consola en blanco:

```
"C:\Users\Satellite C655\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:/Users/Satellite C655/Desktop/Python/dotpy/dotpy/login sencillo/data.py"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta los valores *falsy* None, null y False, te retornarán false al comprobar con un if, puedes usar `if !a: print("no encontrado")`,no olvides poner `a = documento`, ya que  con el print() que pones no te servirá

Comment: `for documento in col.find({'# telefónico':8233323}):   #Query de consulta de mi base de datos
    a = (documento)
    print(a)
    if documento != a:
        print("no encontrado")`
lo hice de esta forma ya que si hago el if !a me da error de sintaxis y pues sigue sin darme algún resultado, no se imprime el "no encontrado" no se si comprendi del todo tu respuesta. Agradecería de que si no entendi tu punto pudieras corregir mi codigo, muchas gracias,

Comment: Bueno lo siento me confundí, no es `!a` es `not a`, en tu código al hacer `if documento!= a` eso siempre dará false, ya que `a = documento`, corrige eso y si sigues teniendo el problema haré una respuesta explicando más a detalle

Comment: Hola, ya encontre la forma, agradezco tu respuesta pero el error era mío desde un inicio ya que estaba iterando el puntero de busqueda cuando lo que debía hacer era simplemente una Query de consulta y la query misma devuelve el none, y ya con eso ya puedo manipular y hacer todo lo que necesite. Por cierto ya respondi la pregunta con la solución pero de todas maneras te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me di cuenta de que estaba usando mal ya que lo que debía hacer no era iterar el puntero de documentos sino que hacer una query de búsqueda y luego plantear el condicional. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
n = "8233323"
doc = col.find_one({
    '# Telefónico':n
})
if doc == None:
    print("No encontrado")
```

Comment: Bien echo, no me había acordado que solo se devuelve un cursor al tener varios documentos, igual puedes hacer `if not doc`